# URL-Format with question mark in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, variables, url, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a controller and this url works fine for me:

```
https://localhost:44332/api/thebest/dosomething/test
```

I'm looking for a way to turn the simple notation into a URL with question marks and parameter name like this:

```
https://localhost:44332/api/thebest/dosomething?text=test
```

How is this possible? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your action probably now looks like this:

```
...
[HttpGet("{text}")]
public ActionResult Test([FromRoute]string test)
```

And to invoke it you just call: `https://localhost:44332/api/thebest/dosomething/test`

To get the result which you need: `https://localhost:44332/api/thebest/dosomething?text=test`

Adjust the action in a following way:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Test([FromQuery]string test)
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help :) Could you accept my answer so that for the rest it will be clear?